# C++ не могу подключить библиотеку Boost на macOS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, boost, clang, clang++

не получается подключить библиотеку на macOS.
IDE: VS Code
Compiler: clang

Error:
`'boost/lambda/lambda.hpp' file not found`

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;

    std::for_each(
        in(std::cin), in(), std::cout << (_1 * 3) << " " );
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(Boost)

# Настройка использования компилятора GCC
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
endif()

# Установка пути к библиотеке Boost
set(BOOST_ROOT "/Users/floyz/cpp-tools/boost_1_82_0/boost")

# Добавление исполняемого файла
add_executable(my_app main.cpp)

# Добавление директорий для поиска заголовочных файлов
target_include_directories(my_app PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Добавление библиотек для линковки
target_link_libraries(my_app PRIVATE ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

set_target_properties(
    my_app PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 20
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
)
```

Ну и на всякий случай **c_cpp_properties.json:**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "/Users/floyz/cpp-tools/boost_1_82_0/boost",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/Users/floyz/cpp-tools/boost_1_82_0"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++23",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64"
        },
        {
            "name": "config-cpp",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++20",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Подскажите в чем проблема?

Comment: `/boost` на конце путей лишний,